# Is there code to get page overview like facebook status

Tags: php, javascript

This might have 30 seconds before closing, but I was wondering if anyone knows of some code in php, javascript etc on github or anywhere else that takes a url and returns a nice synopsis, image etc for the page like the facebook status box?

Comment: You're looking for an opengraph parser.

Comment: I was expecting to be closed as off-topic, maybe but 'Not a real Question'?  I have a ? at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/scottmac/opengraph is a good opengraph scraper. Opengraph tags are how facebook (and google+ and twitter) get those nice synopses. You can use the OG scraper to use get an object that has the info you need and create a nicely formatted block with it.

Scraping OG tags aren't a cure-all though. Many pages on the net were either developed before FB defined the OG or by people who don't care to implement it. In that case, FB also has fallbacks that attempt to infer things things about the page, but are pretty inconsistent in the results.

Comment: Beat the close deadline by an hour.  I'll try it out.  Thanks